# Как запустить проект cmake на Qt в visual studio с параметрами командной строки?

Tags: qt, visual-studio, cmake

Сейчас я запускаю проект без командной строки.
В качестве параметров командной строки нужно будет прописывать имена обрабатываемых файлов.
Проект собирается как CMake, к качестве мейна - файл dsp_test.cpp:

```
//dsp_test.cpp
#include <qobject.h>
#include <qtest.h>
#include "dsp.h"
#include <complex>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
class DspTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void test1() {
        std::string name; std::cin >> name;
        while (name != "#") {
            std::ifstream file(name, std::ios_base::in);
            int cnt = 0;
            double temp;
            QVector<double> _data;
            QVector<double> _timestamps;
            while (!file.eof()) {
                file >> temp;
                ++cnt;
                _timestamps.append(cnt);
                _data.append(temp);
            }

            DSP::Parameters params(_timestamps, _data);
            DSP test_dsp(params);
            double perSNum = test_dsp._parameters._samplingRates[0]->rate() / params._lineFrequency;
            for (int vper = 1; vper <= 10; ++vper) {
                for (int ind = 1; ind <= _data.size(); ++ind) {
                    test_dsp._parameters._valuesCalculationPeriodNumber = vper;
                    test_dsp._parameters._samplingRates.at(0)->setNumberOfSamples(perSNum * vper);
                    std::complex<double> a = test_dsp.getVector(ind);
                    double conv = sqrt(a.real() * a.real() + a.imag() * a.imag());
                    std::cout << vper << " " << ind << " " << conv << "\n";
                    QVERIFY(conv < INFINITY);
                    QVERIFY(conv != NAN);
                }
            }
            std::cin >> name;
        }
    }
};

QTEST_GUILESS_MAIN(DspTest)
#include "dsp_test.moc"
```

Есть 2 cmake файла, один в папке проекта:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(bscope LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) 
 
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS REQUIRED
    Core
)
 
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(tests)

add_library(bscope_static STATIC
    dsp.cpp
    sampling_rate.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(bscope_static PRIVATE Qt::Core)
```

Другой в папке tests, в которой находится dsp_test.cpp:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(tests LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS REQUIRED Core Test)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
  
macro(create_test testsuit_name test_file)
    add_executable(${testsuit_name} ${test_file})
    add_test(NAME ${testsuit_name} COMMAND ${testsuit_name})
    target_link_libraries(${testsuit_name} PRIVATE Qt::Core Qt::Test bscope_static)
    target_include_directories(${testsuit_name} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
endmacro() 
 
create_test(dsp_test dsp_test.cpp)
```

Я гуглил как это сделать, но именно для моего случая ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Что-то у вас странное в коде происходит. Параметры командной строки не обрабатываются, вместо этого код ждет ввод с cin, для теста это не самая лучшая практика

Comment: @BeardedBeaver я понимаю, поэтому и хочу использовать параметры командной строки, но не знаю как. Поэтому и задал вопрос

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал начать тут https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#arguments

Comment: @BeardedBeaver окей, я понял, как вытаскивать арги в коде, но как их передать, если я запускаю проект cmake в visual studio? И как вообще запускать проект visual studio через консоль? Извините что не по теме

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104520/adding-command-line-arguments-to-project оно? я в студии не работал особо